# How to move an asset from one folder to another in Pimcore using PHP API

Tags: php, pimcore

I'm able to upload assets using PHP API in pimcore using the documentation

```
$newAsset = new Pimcore\Model\Asset();
$newAsset->setFilename("myAsset.png");
$newAsset->setData(file_get_contents("some-file.png"));
$newAsset->setParent(Pimcore\Model\Asset::getByPath("/"));
$newAsset->save();
```

What if I want to move that asset from current folder to another using PHP API?

I have tried with the following code, but it didn't worked

```
$asset1 = Pimcore\Model\Asset::getById(132);       // 132 -> asset id 
$asset1->setParentId(11); //11 is the id of the folder created in pimcore. Want to move asset to this folder.
$asset1->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
$parent = Pimcore\Model\Asset::getById(11);
$asset->setParent($parent);
$asset->save();
```

Comment: Instead of id, is it possible to do this ? Like based on parent folder name ?

Comment: You can also get the parent folder by path: Pimcore\Model\Asset::getByPath('/mypath');